# ButtonField = Image No OnClientClick

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, imagebutton, aspxgridview, buttonfield

I want a confirm prompt on this button type. There is no OnClientClick for this button type and I need an alternative method on how.

```
     <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="Content/Images/Edit.png" CommandName="EditRow" Visible="true" CausesValidation="false" ItemStyle-CssClass="smallColumn" ControlStyle-Width="15" ControlStyle-Height="15" />
```

Is there a way I can use Jquery to intercept the button click; prompt the user then if the user says no prevent button click?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can attach a click handler using jQuery:

```
$("#YOUR_BTN_ID").click(function() { if(confirm('YOUR REQUEST HERE') { doSomething(); }));
```

Comment: Thanks brother i hope this work i'll let you know in a second.

Comment: technically my button does not have an ID

Comment: You can find it using using class, parent container, attributes, etc.

Comment: Doesn't work when I do it by class user can hit okay or cancel it doesn't prevent button click.

Comment: Is it a submit button? Use "return false;" in this case